# Need correct way of if condition usage php

Tags: php, if-statement

```
    if($data['params']['by'] == "date" && $data['params']['cnstr_type'] == "1"){
      $this->load->view('profile/report_view/page1', $data);
    } elseif($data['params']['by'] == "date" && $data['params']['cnstr_type'] == "2") {
      $this->load->view('profile/report_view/page2', $data);
    } elseif($data['params']['by'] == "week" && $data['params']['cnstr_type'] == "1") {
      $this->load->view('profile/report_view/page3', $data);
    } elseif($data['params']['by'] == "week" && $data['params']['cnstr_type'] == "2") {
      $this->load->view('profile/report_view/page4', $data);
    }
```

Is there any better way to improve this code

Comment: In what way do you think it might need improvement?

Comment: @BrianPeacock effective way that can reduce code length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than having an ever expanding list of combinations if `if` or `switch` statements, you can have an array which cross references the combinations.  Then you test if the specific combination exists and use the looked up value for the page...

```
$pages = ["date" => [1 =>'profile/report_view/page1',
                    2 =>'profile/report_view/page2'],
          "week" => [1 =>'profile/report_view/page3',
                    2 =>'profile/report_view/page4']
];

if ( isset($pages[$data['params']['by']][$data['params']['cnstr_type']])) {
    $this->load->view($pages[$data['params']['by']][$data['params']['cnstr_type']], $data);
}
```

If the only change is the number of the end, you could even hard code the `profile/report_view/page` part in the call to `$this->load->view()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **switch case** which can simplify your code as

```
switch([$data['params']['by'],$data['params']['cnstr_type']]){

case ["date","1"]:
     $this->load->view('profile/report_view/page1', $data);
     break;

case ["date","2"]:
      $this->load->view('profile/report_view/page2', $data);
      break;
case ["week","1"]:
      $this->load->view('profile/report_view/page3', $data);
      break;

case ["week","2"]:
      $this->load->view('profile/report_view/page4', $data);
      break;
}
```

**This will make your code look more neat.**